# objectdisposedexception was unhandled issue

Tags: c#, sockets

I have this code:

```
private void DownLoaderSession()
{
    try
    {          
        stream = client.GetStream();

        // Buffer for reading data
        byte[] bytes = new byte[256];
        string data = null;
        bool runFlag = true;
        // Enter the listening loop. 
        while (runFlag)
        {
            int recLen = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            // Translate data bytes to a ASCII string.
            data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, recLen);
            // Process the data sent by the client.
            data = data.ToUpper();
            string[] param = data.Split('#');
            switch (param[0])  // CPMMAND
            {
            case "GETFILE":
                FileInfo ftemp = new FileInfo(ClientForm.SharedFolderPath + "\\" + param[1] );   // file name
                fileSize = ftemp.Length;              // size of file in long
                Send("FILEREADY#" + param[1] + "#" + fileSize.ToString());
                UpLoad(param[1]);
                break;
            case "GETALLDETAILS":
                string temp = FindAllDetails(param[1]);
                Send("DETAILSREADY#"+temp);
                this.client.Close();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am sending data from one class to another, at the line:

```
int recLen = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
```

I get the error:

> objectdisposedexception was unhandled

I searched over the internet and I can't find an answer.

Comment: Something's been disposed; probably the stream you're using.

Comment: Where do you set the `runFlag` to false? I see you close the client at some point in the switch. Are you reading from the stream after that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set `runFlag` to `false` after this line:

```
this.client.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

This statement here:

```
 case "GETALLDETAILS":
            string temp = FindAllDetails(param[1]);
            Send("DETAILSREADY#"+temp);
            this.client.Close();
            break;
```

It **closes** the client (assuming it's the `TcpClient`), the stream will be disposed doing that.

The `break;` doesn't break out of the while statement, only the switch case.